# Creating a Window in WinAPI after pressing a button

Tags: c++, winapi, button, window

I'm making an auto clicker for a game in WinAPI and I have 4 simple buttons on the main window. When the user presses the 'start' button I want another window to open asking them for settings such as number of times to click and time between clicks. When I try to create a new window, nothing is happening, but everything else works perfectly.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }

    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            switch (wParam)
            {
            case ID_START:
                {
                    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(CLASS_NAME);

                    HWND settings = CreateWindowEx(
                        0,
                        L"Settings",
                        L"Settings",
                        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
                        100, 100, 600, 200, 
                        NULL,
                        (HMENU) ID_SETTINGS,
                        hInstance,
                        NULL
                        );

                    MSG msg = { };

                    while (GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
                    {
                        TranslateMessage(&msg);
                        DispatchMessage(&msg);
                    }

                    return 0;
                }

            case ID_QUIT:
                {
                    PostQuitMessage(0);
                    return 0;
                }

            case ID_CALIB:
                {
                    if (MessageBox(hwnd, L"You pressed Calibrate", L"Calibrate", MB_OK))
                    {
                        return 0;
                    }
                }

            case ID_INFO:
                {
                    if (MessageBox(hwnd, L"You pressed about", L"About", MB_OK))
                    {
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;

            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

            FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1));
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);

            return 0;
        }       
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

I just started WinAPI today, so I am extremely new. Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: For settings, you may want to launch a dialog instead of creating a normal window.

Comment: Create a dialog template with a dialog editor and a dialog procedure (a little like a window procedure), and call DialogBox at run time. You can also use CreateDialog to do a modeless dialog (more like a normal window) but for a first attempt, I'd stick to a modal dialog (i.e., DialogBox).

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter to CreateWindowEx must be a class name that you registered earlier by calling RegisterClass.

You are specifying WS_CHILD. But a child must have a parent. Pass the parent HWND into the hwndParent parameter.

Comment: After I made the changes you suggested it gave the Linker Error 1168. I changed the parent window argument to hwnd (the handle of the parent) and set the class name to CLASS_NAME which I defined previously in the code.

Comment: 1>LINK : fatal error LNK1168: cannot open C:\Users\Frank Family\Desktop\Sean\C++ Projects\Window\Debug\Window.exe for writing

Comment: Oh, that. Make sure your process ended.

Comment: @x0xRainx0x, Go into task manager and make sure it isn't running. Or hit stop debugging if you're debugging. The code given shouldn't have any reason to do that, though.

Comment: I don't get the linker error anymore (thanks) but it still doesn't work.